# Navigation bar hover effect not working right

Tags: html, css, hover, move

i wanted to make a navigation bar so when i hover buttons they had to have a circle background i could do it but there are another problem that when i hover it, background appearing but it move neighboring elements to left. I tried to add other elements display: block; or smth like this but it also don't working.

Code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 4000px;
    background-color: #F4F3EF;
}

header {
    background-color: #077eff;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 349px;
    padding-right: 322px;
    position: fixed;
}

header .left {
    display: flex;
}

header .left h3 {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
header .left h3 span {
    color: #abdbfe;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

header .right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header .right div,img {cursor: pointer;}

header .right .sign_up {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font-family: Outfit;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

header .right span {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 31px;
}

header .right .moto:hover {
    background-color: rgba(165, 158, 158, 0.4);
    border: 10px solid rgba(165, 158, 158, 0.1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/meal_master/media/chef.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Meal Master - Savor the Flavors, Delight in Every Bite!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="left">
            <img style="margin-top: 23px;" height="50px" width="50px" src="/meal_master/media/chef.png" alt="">
            <h3>Meal<span>Master</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="search_sett">
                <div class="line" style="display: none;"></div>
                <img src="/meal_master/media/search.png" alt="">
                <h4 style="display: none;">Search...</h4>
            </div>
            <img style="margin-left: 22px;" src="/meal_master/media/apps.png" alt="">
            <img class="moto" style="margin: 0 22px 0 22px;" width="40px" height="40px" src="/meal_master/media/fast-delivery.png" alt="">
            <img width="35px" height="35px" src="/meal_master/media/customer-support.png" alt="">
            <span></span>
            <div class="sign_up"><h4>Sign Up</h4></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bootstrap 5 to resolve your issue and simplify the code. Here is an example:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap 5 CDN links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/meal_master/media/chef.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Meal Master - Savor the Flavors, Delight in Every Bite!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Bootstrap 5 navbar component -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="/meal_master/media/chef.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
                Meal Master
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 4000px;
    background-color: #F4F3EF;
}
```

Comment: I dont know bootstrap i wanted to do it only with html and css but thank you anyway